# Understanding Output from import/export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

So I am having kind off a set back understanding the output from Import/Export Statement.

So suppose, if I do something like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cperson from '../components/person/person.js';

console.log(Cperson)
```

I get this as an output in console.log

```
Cpersons() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Cpersons);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (Cpersons.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(Cpersons)).apply(this, arguments));
  }
```

Can someone explain me what is console.log telling?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplication of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137582/how-import-statement-works-in-es6-for-react-components

Otherwise to context might be too broad to explain, please post only errors or issues you are facing. Otherwise you might never get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In react import means to make something available in your current file.
Suppose if you have a component in persons.js you can use it here as 'componentName' with angle brackets

Or if you have file structure like this

module.exports = {

```
Slider_Arrow_Icon: {
  //write your logic here
  back_Arrow_Icon: require('../images/arrow-slide-back'),
  next_Arrow_Icon: require('../images/arrow-slide-next')
```

},

Card: {

```
card: require('../images/payment-icon/card')
```

}

}
then you can import like
import {Slider_Arrow_Icon, Card} form 'filename'